# How to export MySQL 5.5 DB to 5.1 compatible

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1214

I have MySQL 5.6.11 Installed on localhost and i exported a DB to upload on a server that has MySQL 5.1 installed. I get error when i upload

```
SQL query:

--
-- Database: `trintest`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `tr_options`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tr_options` (
`option_id` bigint( 20 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`option_name` varchar( 64 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`option_value` longtext NOT NULL ,
`autoload` varchar( 20 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
PRIMARY KEY ( `option_id` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY `option_name` ( `option_name` ) ,
FULLTEXT KEY `option_value` ( `option_value` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =693;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes
```

but when i import it to MySQL version 5.6.11 it works, but on MySQL 5.1 it shows error above. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the following from MySQL 5.6.11

```
mysqldump -u username -p --compatible=mysql40 databasename > outputfile.sql
```

or

```
mysqldump -u username -p --compatible=mysql323 databasename > outputfile.sql
```

and load outputfile.sql into MySQL 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Mysql 5.1 doesn't support full text index for `InnoDB` tables, so either change your table to `MyISAM` or stick with Mysql version 5.6

for more information:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I'm running into this problem now too and found http://stackoverflow.com/a/20964330/470749 and will check that out.