# #1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Tags: mysql

I'm getting an error saying that the table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indices. How can I achieve this?

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE gamemech_chat (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  from_userid varchar(50) NOT NULL default '0',
  to_userid varchar(50) NOT NULL default '0',
  text text NOT NULL,
  systemtext text NOT NULL,
  timestamp datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  chatroom bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  KEY from_userid (from_userid),
  FULLTEXT KEY from_userid_2 (from_userid),
  KEY chatroom (chatroom),
  KEY timestamp (timestamp)
)  ;
```

*

Answer (score 109):

Before MySQL 5.6 Full-Text Search is supported **only** with MyISAM Engine.

Therefore either change the engine for your table to MyISAM

```sql
CREATE TABLE gamemech_chat (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  from_userid varchar(50) NOT NULL default '0',
  to_userid varchar(50) NOT NULL default '0',
  text text NOT NULL,
  systemtext text NOT NULL,
  timestamp datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  chatroom bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  KEY from_userid (from_userid),
  FULLTEXT KEY from_userid_2 (from_userid),
  KEY chatroom (chatroom),
  KEY timestamp (timestamp)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6635)** demo

or upgrade to 5.6 and use InnoDB Full-Text Search.

Comment: [Some information about the 5.6 InnoDB-Full-Text-Search.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html)

Comment: It turns out that even though my ```Mysql --version``` was correctly showing the latest installation, I was running an older Mysql service.  I had to first stop and uninstall the old Mysql service: http://superuser.com/a/452264/74576, then ```C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin>mysqld --install```, then Windows Start Menu > Search > Services > Mysql > Start

Comment: Is it available in 5.5?

Comment: @KDawg It seems not: *$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1* and I got the error (upgrading Bugzilla; it's 5:19 in the morning, I’m dead tired, have so much going on and haven't kept up with everything) in the question a short bit ago (and too tired to notice anything; it took a few times reading the first sentence in this answer and also looking at *mysql -V* before it occurred to me the problem so I rolled back the changes and all is good - minus the fact the version is out of date and CentOS .. Well maybe you know. Oh well. Answer: no.).

Comment: @KDawg I should say InnoDB does not support FULLTEXT in 5.5.

Comment: ...and this answer ought to be accepted, just as an aside, for whatever it might (not?) be worth (as in my comment).

Answer (score 19):

The problem occurred because of wrong table type.MyISAM is the only type of table that Mysql supports for Full-text indexes.

To correct this error run following sql.

```
 CREATE TABLE gamemech_chat (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  from_userid varchar(50) NOT NULL default '0',
  to_userid varchar(50) NOT NULL default '0',
  text text NOT NULL,
  systemtext text NOT NULL,
  timestamp datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  chatroom bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  KEY from_userid (from_userid),
  FULLTEXT KEY from_userid_2 (from_userid),
  KEY chatroom (chatroom),
  KEY timestamp (timestamp)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 9):

Only MyISAM allows for FULLTEXT, as seen [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6713).

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE gamemech_chat (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  from_userid varchar(50) NOT NULL default '0',
  to_userid varchar(50) NOT NULL default '0',
  text text NOT NULL,
  systemtext text NOT NULL,
  timestamp datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  chatroom bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  KEY from_userid (from_userid),
  FULLTEXT KEY from_userid_2 (from_userid),
  KEY chatroom (chatroom),
  KEY timestamp (timestamp)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 1):

From official reference

> Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables. (In MySQL 5.6 and up, they can also be used with InnoDB tables.) Full-text indexes can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

InnoDB with MySQL 5.5 does not support Full-text indexes.

Answer (score -1):

Simply do the following:

1. Open your .sql file with Notepad or Notepad ++
2. Find InnoDB  and  Replace  all (around 87) with MyISAM
3. Save and now you can import your database with out error.

Answer (score -5):

*************Resolved - #1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes***************

Its Very Simple to resolve this issue. People are answering here in very difficult words which are not easily understandable by the people who are not technical.

So i am mentioning here steps in very simple words will resolve your issue.

1.) Open your .sql file with Notepad by right clicking on file>Edit Or Simply open a Notepad file and drag and drop the file on Notepad and the file will be opened. (Note: Please don't change the extention .sql of file as its still your sql database. Also to keep a copy of your sql file to save yourself from any mishappening)

2.) Click on Notepad Menu Edit > Replace (A Window will be pop us with Find What & Replace With Fields)

3.) In Find What Field Enter **ENGINE=InnoDB** & In Replace With Field Enter **ENGINE=MyISAM**

4.) Now Click on **Replace All** Button

5.) Click **CTRL+S** or **File>Save**

6.) Now Upload This File and I am Sure your issue will be resolved....

Comment: this is an alternative, not a solution

Comment: So you don't like foreign keys?

Comment: @ADTC Thank you for that brilliant laugh! You're absolutely correct too. I would add that programmers don't need GUIs but I’m a heavy command line user (and do not use Windows either)... I'd also add that programmers also don't need to be taught how to upload a file if they even edit it locally (rather than on the server in question in e.g. a staging environment).