# mysql full text search not working

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

i am trying to work with MySQL full text search in table

query:

```
$text="MySQL HTML";
$sql="SELECT * FROM search
          WHERE MATCH (title,title_info) AGAINST ('$text' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

it is supposed to return all rows having both MySQL HTML or MySQL or HTML,
but its not resulting any thing why?

Comment: empty set is being returned.

Comment: Instead of this you can also use like query

Comment: Have you tried to run this query directly from console?

Comment: first check you mysql version if it is less than 5.6 your sql won't work. then see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964269/1214-the-used-table-type-doesnt-support-fulltext-indexes

Comment: Cany you show the create staement and sampled ata?

Answer (score 2):

You must add + sign as prefix to each search term:

```
$text="MySQL HTML";
$text_array = split(' ',$text);
$search_terms = '+'.join($text_array,' +');  // +MySQL +HTML
$sql="SELECT * FROM search
      WHERE MATCH (title,title_info) AGAINST ('$search_terms' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Read more about fulltext search: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
$text="MySQL HTML";
$sql=" SELECT * FROM search 
       WHERE title LIKE '%$text%' OR
       title_info LIKE '%$text%'";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to implement this function will search full text

```
$text = "Test String For You";
$bquery .= getwQuery($text,'title,title_info');

$sql="SELECT * FROM search WHERE ".$bquery;
echo $sql; 
function getwQuery($data, $field_name)
{
    $names_exploded = explode(" ", $data);
    $fname = explode(",", $field_name);
    foreach($names_exploded as $each_name)
    {
        if($each_name != ""):
            $bquery .= " AND (";
            foreach($fname as $fn)
            {
                $bquery .= $fn." LIKE '%".$each_name."%' OR ";
            }
            $bquery = rtrim($bquery,' OR ');
            $bquery .= ')';
        endif;
    }
    $bquery = ltrim($bquery,' AND ');
    return $bquery;
}
```

**Output:**
SELECT * FROM search WHERE (title LIKE '%Test%' OR title_info LIKE '%Test%') AND (title LIKE '%String%' OR title_info LIKE '%String%') AND (title LIKE '%For%' OR title_info LIKE '%For%') AND (title LIKE '%You%' OR title_info LIKE '%You%')