# How to add an index to such sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Please tell me how to add an index to this sql query?

`SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (cities IS NULL) AND (position_id = '2') AND (is_pub = '1')
ORDER BY ordering asc
LIMIT 1`

**Field types:**

- cities = text
- position_id = int(11)
- is_pub = tinyint(1)

I try so:
`ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT ( 'cities', 'position_id', 'is_pub' );`

But I get an error: `The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes`

Comment: Check the cardinality of a field and create index on that particular field or combination of fields. For that cardinality(Uniqueness) is high it is good index. A combination of position_id and is_pub should be good in your query. please provide more context.

Comment: You do not need fulltext index, just a "normal" one. Fulltext index is to search for words within a text.

Answer (score 0):

First, rewrite the query so you are not mixing types.  That is, get rid of the single quotes:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (cities IS NULL) AND (position_id = 2) AND (is_pub = 1)
ORDER BY ordering asc
LIMIT 1;
```

Then, the best query for this is on `table(position_id, is_pub, cities, ordering)`:

```
create index idx_table_4 on table(position_id, is_pub, cities(32), ordering);
```

The first three columns can be in any order in the index, so long as they are the first three.

You should change `cities` to a `varchar()` type.  Is there is reason you want to use a text for this?

Comment: Don't bother with prefixing (`cities(32)`); it is probably useless even in this case.  The OP really needs to change to `varchar` to avoid the prefixing, then use your first suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

You need to change the engine for your table to MyISAM.

possible duplicate of [#1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964269/1214-the-used-table-type-doesnt-support-fulltext-indexes)

Comment: The OP does not need a fulltext index and in recent versions of MySQL even innodb supports fulltext indexes.